# Intercept page exit except from button click in flash/as3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a Live-Chat Application build with Flash/Flex/AS3 embedded in a simple HTML Page.

I want to intercept page exits and to confirm the page exit, when the user clicks on a link or something.

I also have a "stop" button in my flash application, which redirects the user to another page after completed the chat.

How do i intercept everything but the click on that "stop" button?

I have the following JavaScript for now:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Really want to exit?",
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

It works well. But it also asks for confirm when i use the "stop" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). In your JavaScript 
code add this method:

```
function unsetBeforeUnload(){
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

And now in your ActionScript code in "stop" button click handler method add this line:

```
 ExternalInterface.call("unsetBeforeUnload");
```

That's all. May be you'll need to add this line to your Flash object : `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />` in case you don't have it now.

Comment: @nahri Great! i've not test it , so i'm glad twice that it works!